# Sitecore 10 docker containers can't communicate to each other

Tags: docker

I've been trying to launch Sitecore 10 setup from [docker-compose](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/blob/develop/getting-started/docker-compose.yml) in [docker-examples repository](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples).

Compose was failing after spinning first 5 containers: `solr`, `mssql`, `id`, `xconnect`, `cm`.

After some investigation, I've found out that containers can't communicate with each other.
So e.g. cm container can't ping mssql container.

```
docker exec sitecore-xp0_cm_1 ping mssql
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like it might be related to security policies within our company as I've been able to reproduce the same behaviour on other machines within the company. And it's working OK on non-company machines.

The solution that worked for me was to add hostnames to every container.
e.g.:

```
  mssql:
    hostname: mssql
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
```

...

```
  solr:
    hostname: solr
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
```

...

```
  cm:
    hostname: cm
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
```

Full changes can be found [here](https://github.com/VladimirZaverugo/docker-examples/commit/13954acdd849e382adaee76ba5b5ff1235f5ae95#diff-2e7ec88d781255feeb3fe8ff922035bf).

Note, that adding hostname this way will make containers accessible from host machine, so that might cause conflicts if you try to spin up multiple repositories with the same container IDs.

Comment: thanks for this solution, which worked perfectly for me. I've one comment - I found it is better to utilize the variable name, already defined in the .env environment file for those of services, which are mentioned there. 
Like this:
'
  mssql:
    hostname: ${SQL_SERVER}
'

Comment: I have three computers at my home. One from my company. I copied the solution and installed the same docker version everywhere. Only on my companies laptop it would bring the error "Cannot access SQL server..." no matter what. I tried everything, for many days. Finally, these IDs are the solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had an issue with the `id` container name as well.
So besides adding hostnames for all containers I had to also change the hostname for the `id` to `identity` because it did not want to ping and then update the internal reference to it via using the `environment` variable:

```
id:
  hostname: identity
```

...

```
cm:
  hostname: cm
  environment:
    Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority: http://identity
```

Comment: Where does `Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority` come from?

Answer (score 1):

@vzaverugo Our internal team has found an alternate solution by setting the IP address of the docker host entries to something real like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 instead of 127.0.0.1 and stopping the IIS completely. This seems to work fine within our company laptops configured with some policies.

Answer (score 1):

I've had team members experiencing this, where even setting hostnames did not resolve it.

The solution was, switching them from `process` to `hyperv` isolation.

This happened only to some team members, not all. Never did find the root cause. But `hyperv` solved it across the board.