# Docker getting started template: You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions

Tags: docker, sitecore-cli

Hi when i tried to run the docker getting started template from Sitecore i got following error

```
Your login is complete. You can close the browser tab now.

Login information has been saved.

Populating Solr managed schema...

You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned 
additional permissions.

Pushing latest items to Sitecore...

You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions.
```

Its happening after I'm logged-in in Sitecore and accepting the application access in PowerShell it says: `You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions`

[image]

[image]

After looking into the logs I found following log entry:

```
ERROR Error connecting to https://id.myproject.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration: An error occurred while sending the request.
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Infrastructure.HttpMessageHandlerAuthorityReplacer.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you log in using AD integration with your Sitecore environment?

Comment: No i just followed this one https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Comment: Can you make sure this URL https://id.myproject.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration is accessible? It should produce a JSON response

Comment: I am getting same error. Were you able to find any solution to this issue? I am using out of box sitecore starter app.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore CLI needs Identity server for authentication. By sending `dotnet sitecore login`, CLI may be able to open the identity server url in browser and get the access token.

Here, the issue is that your CM environment is not able to connect to Identity server. This is needed to read the `openid-configuration`.  If you are using Docker, you can attach shell to the CM container, `ping {ID domain}` and see it if works.

You can also try logging into Sitecore CM `https://{cm-domain}/sitecore/login` and check whether the login is redirected to Identity server or staying with Sitecore CM login screen url itself `https://{cm-domain}/sitecore/login?fbc=1`. If it stays with CM login screen, then your CM container is not able to reach ID server.

In order to resolve it, you can add hostname to every container as suggested [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26177/1360).