# mssql-init container not able to connect with mssql container

Tags: docker, sql-database, container, xm-cloud

While trying to setup `XMCloud` in local, `mssql-1 container` is build and is healthy. `mssql-init container` throws the below error

```
2023-03-05 11:12:01 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
2023-03-05 11:12:01 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
2023-03-05 11:12:01 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

However, I am able to access the `mssql container instance` from `host ssms`. I checked the `mssql-init environment variable` - sqlserver/sql admin(sa)/sa password in the terminal all seems right.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can direct me how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Try without VPN if you are using any.

Comment: Tried with VPN..without VPN..no luck

Comment: Have you has a chance to solve the issue?

Comment: I had to disable firewall

Comment: did you find a fix to this ? I am facing this locally ...

Comment: In Mmc, check all protocols like named pipe / tcp are enabled

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/sitecore-10-docker-containers-cant-communicate-to-each-other/26177#26177

Have a look on above host name if you provide in docker file  it should resolve ideally